# Move current day's latest files using Talend

Tags: talend, file-management

I have a job in Talend which will connect to a folder and look for the current day's files (based on the name i.e. 20150928_MyFile, 20150928_MySecondFile and 20150928_MyThirdFile ) and will move these files to some other folder. I have used below flemask to look for today's file but this way Talend is moving all the files for today's date but I want it to move only the latest file of today's date for(20150928_MyFile, 20150928_MySecondFile and 20150928_MyThirdFile) each file to be moved.
I have used the below FILE MASK -

```
((String)TalendDate.formatDate("yyyyMMdd", TalendDate.getCurrentDate())) + "*.CSV"
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant trust the current date based mask, because it not necessary to have a file in the NOW moment, but you can use tFileList to get last modified time and in each iteration, get the max last modified time:

```
tFileList-----(iterate)------tJavaRow
    |
    |
(OnSubJobOk)
    |
    .. [the rest of the job]
```

- tFileList can iterate over folder and sort the files by modifiction time.
- tJavaRow get only the first file, use a global variable or context variable to save it.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I tried with this but still the purpose is not solved. I had selected the Order By : Modified date option in tFilelist. Shall I remove the Filemask completely or update it to something else?? Please help...

Comment: @Meen hum! what happened exaclty ? job ended with ok or in error ? whats the output message ? Plz log your job, and put some println in the tjavarow, and make the order action : Desc to get the most recent file.